# EC2 Rails + unicorn 起動スクリプトの設定

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, postgresql, unicorn

Railsアプリの本番環境用にamazon Linux + unicorn + nginx + posgtresql(RDS)の環境を構成中です。

unicornの起動スクリプト作成にあたり色々な情報を参考にしてみたものの起動が失敗してしまいます。

環境
ruby 2.2.2
rails 4.2.3
unicorn 4.9.0
postgresql 9.2.13

起動スクリプト/etc/init.d/unicornの内容

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
# chkconfig: - 85 15
# description: unicorn -- a rails app

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

PROG_NAME=unicorn
USER=ec2-user
APP_ROOT=/home/ec2-user/server
RAILS_ENV=production
PID_FILE=$APP_ROOT/tmp/unicorn.pid
CONFIG_FILE=$APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb
CMD="/usr/local/rbenv/shims/unicorn_rails"
ARGS="-c $CONFIG_FILE -D -E $RAILS_ENV"

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

case $1 in
  start)
    daemon --user=$USER --pidfile=$PID_FILE $CMD $ARGS
    ;;
  stop)
    killproc -p $PID_FILE $PROG_NAME -QUIT
    ;;
  restart)
    killproc -p $PID_FILE $PROG_NAEE -USR2
    ;;
  *)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

`sudo service unicorn start`実行時のエラーログは下記のようになっています。

```
I, [2015-10-15T09:31:03.537055 #17233]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 17236 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2015-10-15T09:31:03.537134 #17233]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 17238 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2015-10-15T09:31:03.537193 #17233]  INFO -- : master complete
I, [2015-10-15T09:32:27.797578 #17708]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2015-10-15T09:32:29.038911 #17708]  INFO -- : unlinking existing socket=/home/ec2-user/server/tmp/unicorn.sock
I, [2015-10-15T09:32:29.039043 #17708]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/home/ec2-user/server/tmp/unicorn.sock fd=11
E, [2015-10-15T09:32:29.070183 #17708] ERROR -- : fe_sendauth: no password supplied
 (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

`PG::ConnectionBad`とありますのでpostgresql関係の問題だと思いますが色々なサイトを見ても特にunicorn側でデータベースについて何か設定している様子がなくエラーの理由がわかりません。railsのdatabase.ymlのプロダクションDBの設定ではRDSで設定したDB名・ユーザ名・パスワード(環境変数)及びホストを設定しておりrake db:migrateコマンドでテーブルの作成はできています。

Answer (score 1):

確認できる環境がないので推測ですが・・正しくunicornが起動してないような気がします。
たぶん、RAILS_ENVの値がセットできてないんじゃないかと。

原因は`unicorn_rails`コマンドだと思います。
これはいわばRails 1, 2用のコマンドです。
Rails3からはRackアプリケーションになっているので、`unicorn`コマンドを使用するように変更してみてください。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325923/what-is-the-difference-between-unicorn-and-unicorn-rails/12326124#12326124

http://unicorn.bogomips.org/unicorn_rails_1.html

Comment: コマンドをunicorn_railsからunicornに変更してみましたがやはり同じエラーが発生してしまいます。PG::ConnectionBadの後は次のような表示が沢山でます。
/home/ec2-user/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `initialize'

Comment: そうでしたか。。
それでは、database.ymlの内容を追記していただけませんか？
パスワードを環境変数で指定しているとのことですが、sudo serviceコマンドを実行するときと、rake db:migrateをするときの環境変数が異なってるような気がしてます。